# How to add 1 hour to event's end date dynamically?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I would like to add 1 hour to event's start date and set it to end date. Whenever I try use moment's add function, I would get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined
>       at D (moment.min.js:28)
>       at e (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at xb (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at xb (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at xb (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.r.param (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. ((index):385)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Below is my code:

```
function loadCalendar(batch) {
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: moment("2016-12-11"),
        utc: true,
        header: false,
        columnFormat: 'dddd',
        allDaySlot: false,
        hiddenDays: [0],
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: '07:00:00',
        maxTime: '21:00:00',
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        lazyFetching: true,
        eventOverlap: false,
        events: {
            editable: true
        },
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            classname = $(this).attr("id");  
        },
        eventReceive: function(event) {
//                                    classname = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(classname);
            $("#new-subj").modal("show");

            $("#save-subj").click(function() {
//                                        var batch = $(".course").text();
                var subjcode = $("#subjcode").val();
                var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS+08:00");
                var end = moment(start).add(1, "hour");
                var prof = $("#prof").val();
                var profname = $("#prof option:selected").text();
                var room = $("#room").val();
                var roomname = $("#room option:selected").text();
                var course = $("#course-hidden").val();
                var yrlvl = $("#yrlvl-hidden").val();
//                                        var classname = $(this).css("background-color");

                $.ajax({
                    url: eventurl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        batch: batch,
                        subjcode: subjcode,
                        prof: prof,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        room: room,
                        course: course,
                        yrlvl: yrlvl,
                        classname: classname,
                        action: "add"
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        event.id = data.eventid;
                        console.log(data.eventid);
                        event.title = subjcode;
                        event.description = profname + "<br/>" + roomname;
                        event.className = classname;
                        calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

                        $("select").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log("adding event: "+e.responseText);
                    }
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
                $("#new-subj").modal("hide");
            });

            $("#cancel-subj").click(function() {
                calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                getEvents();
            });
        },
        eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            if (isElemOverDiv(jsEvent)) {
                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure you want to delete this subject?",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "",
                    confirmButtonText: "Delete",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function(isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: eventurl,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                id: event.id,
                                action: "delete"
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                if (data.status == "success") {
                                    console.log(event.id);
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                                        getEvents();
                                        swal("Deleted", "The subject has been deleted.", "success");
                                    }, 2000);
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(e){ 
                                console.log('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem must be with "event.start". Check in debugger the value of "event.start" and then the value of the variable "start". It is easiest to check this directly in your debugger console.

Comment: I tried, but I still got the error. But when I change `var end = moment(start).add(1, "hour");` to `var end = event.start;`, the error disappears.

Comment: check also if moment is available and which one. THere is also moment that comes with fullcalendar. If you provide a fiddle I can do more research. I did a fiddle for the moment part and it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own problem by using `moment(event.start).add(1, "h").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");`. Moment reads the date as an invalid ISO format so I think I needed to format it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. For an event, set the start and end dates of the event object as follows:

```
event.end = event.start.add(moment.duration("01:00:00"));
```

If your event.start is not a moment object, you might have to do `event.end = moment(event.start) ...` to make add work.

Comment: This wasn't really the answer, but it helped. I've solved my own problem by using `moment(event.start).add(1, "h").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");`. Moment reads the date as an invalid ISO format so I think I needed to format it. Thank you nevertheless!